# Vue.js with Tween.js example does throws error

Tags: vue.js, tween.js

I want to use tween.js to animate a changing number (which I pass from a computed prop)

I did exactly what is described in this example: https://alligator.io/vuejs/tween-values-tweenjs/
(which uses the example from the official docs (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html#Animating-State-with-Watchers)

The only code I added is this line straight after the opening `<script>` in my component "AnimatedCounter"

```
var TWEEN = require('@tweenjs/tween.js');
```

But I get this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toFixed' of undefined
> at TWEEN.Tween.eval [as _onUpdateCallback] (webpack-internal:///1222:58)
> at TWEEN.Tween.update (webpack-internal:///1156:390)
> at _Group.update (webpack-internal:///1156:66)
> at animate (webpack-internal:///1222:51)

Comment: The alligator.io example deviates from the example in the docs. Please show your code.

Comment: @thanksd I am using is the exact code from alligator.io component. in my other component where i use AnimatedCounter I do: <animated-counter :value="myComputedProp"> - Thats all

Comment: So you have this line `const myTween = new TWEEN.Tween({ tweeningValue: start })` and this line `this.tweeningValue = myTween.tweeningValue.toFixed(0)` exactly?

Comment: yes exactly, just copied it over like this

Comment: @Nicensin can you post your code solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will answer this myself.
I cant exactly figure out, why the example from alligator.io did not work.
But I solved it with the original example by [vuejs.org](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html#Animating-State-with-Watchers)

So I used TweenLite from https://github.com/greensock/GreenSock-JS like the example does and this works just finde. So I guess https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/ was not the correct Library for this.

Answer (score 1):

Ho!

This is a little bit older, but i fixed it with

I had to replace `this.tweeningValue = myTween.tweeningValue.toFixed(0)`

with: `this.tweeningValue = myTween._object.tweeningValue.toFixed(0)`

I'm not sure if there is a common way to enter `_objects` but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue with the example from the official docs. The problem is the context/scope, I guess.

Replace:

```
.onUpdate(() => {
  this.tweeningValue = myTween.tweeningValue.toFixed(0)
})
```

with

```
.onUpdate((object) => {
  this.tweeningValue = object.tweeningValue.toFixed(0)
})
```

Since I used the official example, the full tween method now reads like this:

```
tween: function (startValue, endValue) {
  var vm = this
  function animate () {
    if (TWEEN.update()) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }
  }

  new TWEEN.Tween({ tweeningValue: startValue })
    .to({ tweeningValue: endValue }, 500)
    .onUpdate(function (object) {
      vm.tweeningValue = object.tweeningValue.toFixed(0)
    })
    .start()

  animate()
}
```

And it works perfectly fine with `@tweenjs/tween.js`.